# Realizing a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(S_g)$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{Isom}^+(S_g)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, mapping-class-groups

Let $G\leq \operatorname{Homeo}^+(S_g)$ be finite, where $S_g$ is a closed, connected, orientable surface of genus at least $2$. Then I have the following questions:

(1) Can $G$ always be realized as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Diffeo}^+(S_g)$ for some smooth structure on $S_g$?

(2) Can $G$ always be realized as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Isom}^+(S_g)$ for some hyperbolic metric on $S_g$?

Note that:
(a) The questions are equivalent.

(b) Nielsen-Realization theorem is not helpful in the above context as it starts with a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{Mod}(S_g)$.

(c) Originally I wanted to prove that the restriction of the natural projection map $ \operatorname{Homeo}^+(S_g)\to \operatorname{Mod}(S_g)$ to $G$ is injective. In Farb and Margalit's "A primer on mapping class groups" it is written that this follows from Theorem 6.8 (which says that the Torelli group is torsion free) but I am not able to deduce it from this theorem.

Comment: For (2), can't you just average any hyperbolic metric over $G$?  (This is the standard trick for unitarising a complex, linear representation of a finite group—but I'm no geometer, and maybe it breaks something about the geometry.)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225355/finite-groups-of-planar-homeomorphsims

Comment: @LSpice: (1)=>(2) First, average any Riemannian metric to get a G-invariant Riemannian metric then apply the uniformization theorem to obtain a hyperbolic metric in the conformal class of the earlier metric which realizes G as isometries. (2)=>(1) is trivial. But note that, averaging a metric would require maps in G to be diffeomorphism. Here I'm starting with a group in Homeo+(S_g).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454805/realizing-a-finite-subgroup-of-mathrmhomeos-g-as-a-subgroup-of-mathrm#comment1177496_454805), ah, got it, thanks.  (So it potentially breaks even the topology, not just he geometry!)

Comment: Wat you wanted to prove in (c) is true. The kernel of the projection is torsion-free and thus intersects trivially with the finite group G. To see why it is torsion-free, you can see the answers at the post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250032/is-mathrmdiff-0s-g-torsion-free)

Comment: @MoisheKohan - Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Moishe Kohan’s comment turned into an answer.

---

Suppose that $S$ is a closed, connected, oriented surface of genus at least two.  Let $\rho \colon \mathrm{Homeo}^+(S) \to \mathrm{MCG}^+(S)$ be the homomorphism taking a homeomorphism to its isotopy class. Suppose that $G < \mathrm{Homeo}^+(S)$ is the given finite subgroup.  By (c) we have that $\rho|G$ is an isomorphism.  Let $G^* = \rho(G)$.  By Nielsen realisation there is a metric on $S$, and a subgroup $G^{**} < \mathrm{Homeo}^+(S)$ so that $\rho|G^{**}$ is an isomorphism to $G^*$ and so that $G^{**}$ acts on $S$ via isometries.  Let $\mathcal{O} = S/G^{**}$ be the resulting orbifold.

**Claim**: $S / G$ is homeomorphic (as an orbifold) to $\mathcal{O}$.

**Proof**: If $G$ acts freely then we are done. So, suppose that $x \in S$ be a point that is fixed by some non-identity element of $G$. Let $G_x$ be the stabiliser of $x$.  We lift the action of $G_x$ to the universal cover of $S$ (choosing of course the lifts that fix a chosen preimage of $x$).  By the [result](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225355/finite-groups-of-planar-homeomorphsims) Moishe Kohan points at in the comments the lifted action is by (rational!) rotations.  $\square$

Using this and "transfer of structure" the answers to (1) and (2) are "yes".  I think this means that $G$ and $G^{**}$ are in fact conjugate.